# Why I set Visible Gone for Navigation Drawer but it don't work and set inflaterMenu but error

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am writing abstract class Activity contain toolbar and Navigation Drawer

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/mLayoutDrawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">



 <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mNavDrawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and this is base activity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected Toolbar mToolbar;
protected FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
protected DrawerLayout mLayoutDrawer;
protected NavigationView mNavDrawer;
protected ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;


protected boolean setNavigation()
{
    return false;
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

initView()


if (setNavigation())

        {

            mNavDrawer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new         ActionBarDrawerToggle(BaseActivity.this,mLayoutDrawer,mToolbar,R.string.app_name,R.string.app_name);

            mLayoutDrawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    }
   }


private void initView() {


    mLayoutDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayoutDrawer);

    mNavDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.mNavDrawer);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);

}


 /**
 * method used in order to return the menu of the Navigation Drawer and return the listener to set to the Navigation Drawer.
 * @return the resource ID of the menu to set + the   OnNavigationItemSelectedLister of the Navigation Drawer to set.
 */


protected void setNaviMenu(int menu,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener listener)
{
    if (setNavigation())
    {
        mNavDrawer.inflateMenu(menu);
        mNavDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }
}

protected void setNaviHeader(int layoutHeader)
{
    if (setNavigation())
    {
        mNavDrawer.addHeaderView(getView(layoutHeader));
    }
}
}
```

But when I `setNavigation()` both true and false Navigation drawer shows. It wasn't hidden. And when set `setNaviMenu` is faulty

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{vn.namtran/vn.namtran.MainActivity}: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020054 at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) at                     
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by: 
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f020054 at 
android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1139) at 
android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:714) at 
android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)  at 
android.support.v7.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:147) at 
android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421) at        
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.pr
epareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:485) at 
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.update(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:426) at 
android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:113) at 
android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateMenu(NavigationView.java:233) at vn.namtran.BasicActivity.BaseActivity.setNaviMenu(BaseActivity.java:51)  at 
vn.namtran.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36) at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5258) at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2239) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243) at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5372) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:970) at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you share your `styles.xml`?